# have sphinx report broken links

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

When building html documentation, how do you force sphinx to report, or create an error, on links that don't exist?

Specifically, I have properties and methods within my Python project that have been removed or renamed, and it is hard to find all the dead links with the sphinx generated html output.

I feel like I'm staring at the answer here:
http://sphinx-doc.org/glossary.html, as descriped in the opening paragraph.

I'm obviously not understanding something.

Answer (score 18):

Set the [nitpicky](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-nitpicky) configuration variable to `True` (you can also use the [-n option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-n) when running sphinx-build).

In nitpicky mode, a cross-reference to a function (such as `` :func:`myfunc` ``), class, or other object that cannot be found will generate a warning message.

Comment: awesome, adding "nitpicky = True" in the projects conf.py file fixed it.

Comment: very nice answer! is there a way to redirect those warnings to a file?

Comment: @jsmedmar, have you tried to use the [**-w**](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-w) option?

Comment: still does not work for internal links like \`Link to doc chapter <../folder/chapter.html>`_

Comment: @Donatello: That looks like a link to a HTML document. I would not expect "nitpicky" to detect bad links to non-reST targets.

Comment: @mzjn yes, but indeed, there is no internal link check capability for internal HTML links, whereas it works for external links (using [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511047/1034782)) , that's too bad !

Answer (score 9):

I think [`CheckExternalLinksBuilder`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/builders.html#sphinx.builders.linkcheck.CheckExternalLinksBuilder) is what you're looking for.

It's basically used by calling 'sphinx-build' with `-b linkcheck` option. Please see [`sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html?highlight=linkcheck) for more info. Also, take a look at the list of sphinx-extensions [here](http://sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extensions.html) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib).

Comment: That doesn't work for finding properties and methods within my Python project that have been removed or renamed. It appears to work for external links only.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm not sure that finding broken properties or methods is the job for Sphinx. Sounds like pylint, pyflakes are right tools for the job.