# How can I check internal links in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx can check external links using http://sphinx-doc.org/builders.html?highlight=linkcheck#sphinx.builders.linkcheck

But how to check internal links?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14735060/407651

Comment: @mzjn I have a reference to an CSV file that goes 404 when clicked. With 'Nitpicky = True' it still doesn't show up in the make log.
It's just a normal internal link `\`Sample CSV file <Folder/CSV-Data-Example.csv>\`_`

Comment: That kind of link is considered by the linkcheck builder (it is a "local" link). But there is no real check that the link target actually exists. The result in output.txt is simply something like `index.rst:5: [local] Folder/CSV-Data-Example.csv`.