# Python - Sphinx check domain links

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How do you report errors if [Sphinx domains](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html) such as `` :func:`my_function_name` `` don't point to a valid link? Ideally I'd like a tool that can check **just code-related domains and nothing else** and return these broken links as errors so that they can be used for CI purposes.

### Ideal/Desired Tool

Something that, when run, will go through Python files and print the line/column number where there's a link issue. e.g.

`link-checker my_module.py`

```
my_module.py|4|6|:func:`get_foo`|Missing link
my_module.py|4|8|:attr:`some.thing`|More than one target
```

This specific of a tool may not exist but that's the absolute ideal. But if the tool just reports missing links coming from `.rst` files, that'd be good enough, since most of my docstrings become API documentation anyway. `nitpicky` and `linkcheck` almost work, but don't.

### Current Problems Using `nitpicky`

There's a `-n` or `nitpicky` option that does what I'm looking for. The problem is, it isn't suitable for CI because it captures too many false-positives.

Example: [This post, which recommends enabling nitpicky or the -n option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735060/3626104)

For example, take this napoleon, "Google-style" docstring:

```py
def foo(bar=8):
    """Do something.

    Args:
        bar (int, optional): Some information here.

    """
    pass
```

nitpicky returns

```
WARNING: py:class reference target not found: int
WARNING: py:class reference target not found: optional
```

Neither `int` or `optional` are meant to be interpreted as a `py:class`. But it treated it as one anyway.

### Current Problems Using `linkcheck`

[Another answer from the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511047/3626104) recommends using linkcheck. As far as I can see, it has the same problems as nitpicky. I'd love to use something like `sphinx-build -b linkcheck foo bar -W` to change the warnings into errors so that CI tools can use it. But because it reports so many false positives, it'll spam the user with unnecessary info.

### Summary

`linkcheck` would work good enough if just checked Sphinx domains such as `py:class`, `py:func`, etc and wasn't erroring on all those false positives. Maybe there's a way to set that up? I didn't see anything useful in the documentation or source code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [napoleon extension](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/default/napoleon/)?

Comment: "For example, take this napoleon, "Google-style" docstring"

Comment: I'm not sure why you're mentioning napoleon extension. AFAIK it only adds google-style and numpy support. It doesn't have anything to do with Sphinx domains. I could be missing something though. Would you please explain?

Comment: Perhaps [`nitpick_ignore`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-nitpick_ignore) would help?